# Deployment liferay plug-in project on liferay-portal-jboss-6.2-ce-ga2

Tags: eclipse, jboss, liferay

I had a `liferay plug-in` project which is developed on eclipse luna ide, tomcat server, `liferay sdk 6.2`, i built it to war file, and now i want to deploy my project on `liferay jboss`. And here what i did:
1. I put my war file to deploy folder in `liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\deploy`
2. I start jboss server `liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\jboss-7.1.1\bin\standalone.bat`
And i got this error in log file

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ciren-portlet.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ciren-portlet.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "ciren-portlet.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119)[jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018014: Failed to parse XML descriptor "/C:/Users/ttcgcn123/Desktop/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/jboss-7.1.1/standalone/deployments/ciren-portlet.war/WEB-INF/web.xml" at [898,3]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

And here my `web.xml file` 
[View web.xml](http://www.mediafire.com/view/409swtqmfv836g7/web.xml)
[Download web.xml](http://www.mediafire.com/download/409swtqmfv836g7/web.xml)

Comment: Is `ciren-portlet.war` your WAR file (please add this information to your question)? Funny thing, it is complaining about line 898 where your posted web.xml has only 128 lines. Could you please check if the file given in the stacktrace is exactly the one you have provided?

Answer (score 0):

Just a small addition here, you are required to login to your liferay portal using admin, and then select Admin > Control Panel.